# How to find Windows Server and Visual Studio version used in agent pool that are configured in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, agent

How to find Windows Server and  Visual Studio version  used in agent pool that are configured in azure devops .

Answer (score 0):

You can find all OS and Visual Studio versions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent